# MemoryError with SGDClassifier with chunksize = 100

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

So I have a text document with 53 million rows with their category labels and I am trying to fit classifiers for this multi-class classification problem using scikit-learn.

I have tried a lot of things and I just cannot solve this problem anymore.

So I am loading the data in chunks using pandas with chunk size = 100

vectorizing the data using HashingVectorizer and using SGDClassigier.partial_fit on my data.

I am getting a memory error which is inherently erroneous since the sparse array is 9992 bytes in memory (I checked using data.nbytes)

The code is:

```
data_iterator = pd.read_csv(foo,chunksize=100)
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()
classifier = SGDClassifier(n_jobs=-1,verbose=1)

for data_set in data_iterator:
    data_set = data_set.dropna()
    X = data_set[data_set.columns[1]]
    y = data_set[data_set.columns[0]]
    X_train = vectorizer.transform(X)
    classifier.partial_fit(X_train,y,classes=unique_ids)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 168, in _allocate_parameter_mem
    dtype=np.float64, order="C")

MemoryError

What do I do? I have been trying this for a very long time

**EDIT:**
Okay, I figured the issue out. I have 1e5 number of classes in my dataset. If I use a 1000 classes it works. The number of classes I have is creating a problem. How do I solve get around that issue?